# Reuse SSIS package in databases with different collations: The column can not be processes because more than one codepage was specified

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I have an SSIS package which should run in several databases with same schema but different collations.

When I change to another database with a different collation than the one with I created the package, I receive an error message saying than more than one codepage was specified and need to update package metadata.

Is there some way to skip this or will I have to build different version of the package for each different database collation?

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering your query to explicitly collate the column

i.e.

```
SELECT 
COL1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
COL2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
COL3 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
ANumberField
FROM YourTable
```

Assuming it can perform the collation automatically, this should keep the collation consistent.

Or you could try a cast to NVARCHAR (unicode)

```
SELECT 
CAST(COL1 As NVARCHAR(100)) COL1,
CAST(COL2 As NVARCHAR(100)) COL2,
CAST(COL3 As NVARCHAR(100)) COL3,
ANumberField
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason there are different collations is to support different languages. If I follow your advice, it's not possible to end with unrecognized characters in my destination database?

Comment: ....or an error will occur because it can't convert the collation. At the very least you need to load these into NVARCHAR (unicode) fields in the target so you never have to worry about collation again. But I'm not certain how to get these in in a consistent manner. You might indeed have to create a package per collation. You may wish to do some research on BIML which helps you automatically build packages.

Comment: You can also use COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

Comment: or maybe a cast to NVARCHAR might help.